# Add items to a has_many relation on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a has_many relation work for object to be created.

It is a simple case and despite many efforts and researches through the web, I cannot find why my code is not working.

I have the following classes *(note: some variables use French names)*:

```
class Comptes::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
  has_many :transactions, through: :categorizations

  validates :nom, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Comptes::Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

  ... # some validations
end

class Comptes::Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :category

  validates :transaction, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

Category and Transaction are the basic models and Categorization is dedicated to the association (this is a basic account - transaction system).

**What I can do** is create a transaction and a category then fill transaction.categories with the category (transaction has thus an id).
**What I cannot do** is:

```
transaction = Comptes::Transaction.new ...
category = Comptes::Category.first
transaction.categories << category
# OR
transaction.categorizations.build category: category
# OR
# use categorizations_attributes in and accepts_nested_attributes_for.
```

Thank you very much for any help

**Edit**: this is done in rails 4.0.0
And I found that the issue was coming from the validation in Comptes::Categorization.
This prevents creation of new categorizations if the transaction or category does not exist yet.

**Update (18/08/2014)**: the issue is coming from the validation in Categorizations, which prevent from creating the association without existing transaction and category. This may be an issue in rails 4.0.0. To see...

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction` class is not under the module `Comptes`. Therefore, when you do `has_many :categorizations` or `has_many :categories` in it, the corresponding models are inferred as `Categorization` and `Category` *instead of* `Comptes::Categorization` and `Comptes::Category`.

To resolve this, you need to specify the **class_name option of the association** because the name of the model can't be inferred from the association name.

Update the class `Transaction` as below:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, class_name: "Comptes::Categorization" , dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations, class_name: "Comptes::Category"
end
```

Comment: Actually, it is just a copy-error. Transaction also belong the module Comptes. I will update my question.